# Race condition with converters?

Tags: c#, wpf, converters, race-condition

I have a wpf form that has quite a few dynamically created controls e.g. `ComboBox`es.

On each `ComboBox` I have a few converters to handle business logic.  One of the converters auto-populates `N/A` and disabled it based on other input on the form.  However, this should only be allowed to be auto-populated (the user should not be able to select this).

To accomplish this, I have a converter on the `ItemsSource` of the ComboBox that filters out the `N/A` option if the `ComboBox` is enabled, otherwise I include it so it can be populated as needed.  I also have a converter for the SelectedItem to auto-populate the `N/A` answer.

However, there seems to be a race condition in that the converters do not fire in the same order consistently, resulting in blank answers (the converter to auto-populate the selecteditem is running before the ItemsSource converter is running to add the answer).

Is there anyway to ensure that the converters execute in the same manner?  I am creating the bindings/converters in the code-behind (since the controls are created dynamically) if that makes a difference.

EDIT: Adding in my code per request (however my question is more of a general question).  Here is my code behind where I am defining the bindings/converters (I have a template of each control in my xaml and I am cloning it here as well):

```
            //Filter out AnswerOptions (N/A, Yes, No) based on other questions
        MultiBinding itemsSourceBinding = new MultiBinding();
        itemsSourceBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("ParentForm.BaselineQuestionsProperty.ImageAdequacyProperty.SingleAnswer") { Source = this });
        itemsSourceBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding(".") { Source = containerBase });
        itemsSourceBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("ParentForm.BaselineQuestionsProperty.MissingTOptionProperty.IsSelected") { Source = this });
        itemsSourceBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("ParentForm.BaselineQuestionsProperty.MissingLOptionProperty.IsSelected") { Source = this });
        itemsSourceBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("AnswerOptions") { Source = containerBase });
        itemsSourceBinding.Converter = new EndplateAnswerFilterConverter();
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(comboBox, ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, itemsSourceBinding);

        //Binding to auto-populate Answers based on Image Adequacy Answer
        MultiBinding singleAnswerBinding = new MultiBinding();
        singleAnswerBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("ParentForm.BaselineQuestionsProperty.ImageAdequacyProperty.SingleAnswer") { Source = this });
        singleAnswerBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding(".") { Source = containerBase });
        singleAnswerBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("ParentForm.BaselineQuestionsProperty.MissingTcOptionProperty.IsSelected") { Source = this });
        singleAnswerBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("ParentForm.BaselineQuestionsProperty.MissingLOptionProperty.IsSelected") { Source = this });
        singleAnswerBinding.Converter = new EndplateNotReadabletoAnswerConverter();
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(containerBase, ContainerBase.SingleAnswerProperty, singleAnswerBinding);
```

Here are my converters:

ItemsSource converter to filter out answers:

```
    public class EndplateAnswerFilterConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] is Answer && values[1] is ContainerBase && values[2] is bool && values[3] is bool && values[4] is ObservableCollection<Answer> /*targetType == typeof(Visibility)*/)
        {
            ObservableCollection<Answer> itemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Answer>();

            var answerOptions = (ObservableCollection<Answer>)values[4];
            var imageAdequacyAnswer = (Answer)values[0];
            var containerBase = (ContainerBase)values[1];
            var missingTOptionSelected = (bool)values[2];
            var missingLOptionSelected = (bool)values[3];

            //Loop through AnswerOptions
            foreach (var ans in answerOptions)
            {
                //Add N/A option if NR/Missing Images
                if (ans.Value == ((int)YesNoAnswers.NotApplicable).ToString() &&
                    (imageAdequacyAnswer.Value == ((int)ImageAdequacyAnswers.NotReadable).ToString() ||
                    (missingTOptionSelected && containerBase.Name.Contains("_T")) ||
                    (missingLOptionSelected && containerBase.Name.Contains("_L"))))
                {
                    itemsSource.Add(ans);
                }
                //Add Yes/No otherwise
                else if (ans.Value != ((int)YesNoAnswers.NotApplicable).ToString() &&
                    !(imageAdequacyAnswer.Value == ((int)ImageAdequacyAnswers.NotReadable).ToString() ||
                    (missingTOptionSelected && containerBase.Name.Contains("_T")) ||
                    (missingLOptionSelected && containerBase.Name.Contains("_L"))))
                {
                    itemsSource.Add(ans);
                }
            }

            return itemsSource;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Converter to auto-populate the combobox (ContainerBase is a custom user control that encapsulates the `ComboBox` with other properties as well):

```
    public class EndplateNotReadabletoAnswerConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] is Answer && values[1] is ContainerBase && values[2] is bool && values[3] is bool /*targetType == typeof(Visibility)*/)
        {
            var imageAdequacyAnswer = (Answer)values[0];
            var containerBase = (ContainerBase)values[1];
            var missingTOptionSelected = (bool)values[2];
            var missingLOptionSelected = (bool)values[3];

            if (imageAdequacyAnswer.Value == ((int)ImageAdequacyAnswers.NotReadable).ToString() ||
                (missingTOptionSelected && containerBase.Name.Contains("_T")) ||
                (missingLOptionSelected && containerBase.Name.Contains("_L")))
            {
                return containerBase.GetAnswerOptionByValue(((int)YesNoAnswers.NotApplicable).ToString());
            }

            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A race condition requires at least two threads. I doubt that your converters are running on different threads.

Comment: Questions like yours are always difficult enough to answer, but without even a line of code... virtually impossible.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen A race condition can easily happen with a single thread, if you are processing a collection of items and order of processing is not deterministic but you write your code expecting it to be deterministic.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I wouldn't call that a race condition, but let's not argue about that.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking there might be a situation where you are getting two different converters; hence two different data sets created and an apparent race condition.

To solve any possible issues with such a race condition I recommend that these two steps be done; both of them could be done independently but it is advised to do both together.

1. Within the converter(s) put in `lock` sections and lock a sync object to stop any dual access/creation of the items to ultimately go to the combos.
2. Create a singleton based converter where the converter is responsible for its own creation and only one converter regardless of what page needs a converter gets the *exact same one*.

To have a converter create itself I recommend that a generic base class be created which handles the singleton creation of the converter and servers up the converter(s). I am basing the following code off of my blog article entitled [Xaml: Call Binding Converter Without Defining StaticResource in Xaml Thanks to Markup Derived Base Class in C#](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1000).

In that article one never creates the static resource converter in xaml, but will directly call the converter in Xaml such as:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Omega.Operation.Converters"
        ...
        >

<Combo ItemsSource="{Binding ComboData, 
                       Converter={ converters:EndplateAnswerFilterConverter } 
                      }">
```

To achieve the direct binding of the converter and the creation of the *one* converter in the singleton the following base class will need to be implemented:

```
/// <summary>
/// This creates a Xaml markup which can allow converters (which inheirit form this class) to be called directly
/// without specify a static resource in the xaml markup.
/// </summary>
public  class CoverterBase<T> : MarkupExtension where T : class, new()
 {
    private static T _converter = null;

    public CoverterBase() { }

    /// <summary>Create and return the static implementation of the derived converter for usage in Xaml.</summary>
    /// <returns>The static derived converter</returns>
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return _converter ?? (_converter = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T), null));
    }
}
```

Finally the converter itself will need to specify its base:

```
  namespace Omega.Operation.Converters
    {

     public class EndplateAnswerFilterConverter : CoverterBase<EndplateAnswerFilterConverter>, 
                                                       System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
           lock (syncObject)
           {}
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
          lock (syncObject)
            {}       
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Would a singleton approach work here?  The controls are created dynamically in a grid pattern e.g. 1 row contains 4 to 5 different controls.  The controls in each row should have the same behavior, but independent of the other rows - The control in a given column must have it's own instance of the converter for each row (e.g. I need an `EndplateAnswerFilterConverter` for a `ComboBox` for Row 2, another one for the `ComboBox` in row 3, etc.)

Comment: @Saggio The code above may/may not work, for it is unclear *to me* why the converters are not behaving in a consistent manner but exhibit a race condition as you put it. A converter should be `stateless` and simply handle input as it is provided. The only thing I can think of is the converters may be called erroneously during initialization before data has been loaded and the `race` condition appears due to the invalid data of the first initialization. I agree that a singleton may not be the answer, but it could be a way to eliminate failure due to state from multiple converter instances.